# Suggestions for a new IDE/text editor

Tags: ide, text, editor

I've been in search for a good text editor/IDE which is cross-platform and supports Mercurial, Git, or allows me to add in other version control systems.

I've pretty much run the gauntlet on free programs and now I'm willing to buy a license for a good program thats under $100 (I qualify for academic discounts if applicable).

I typically do work in assembly, C, C++, Java, and yacc/lex. I'd really like a way to interface with project shell scripts and makefiles as well. SSH support would be great too.

I was wondering if anyone has suggestions on a good proprietary editor that has version control plugins and is cross platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around a little bit and came across [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/), which I really like the look of.

I couldn't use emacs, as I am a very proud vim user. I'm just looking for something a little more polished than vim or emacs but not quite as heavyweight as Netbeans or Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

I can recommend Eclipse highly.

Comment: +1. If it doesn't have what you need, there's a plugin for it.

Comment: Yep Eclipse is good for what you want, just make sure you install the JDT (Java), CDT(C/C++), scripts (Shelled).  You can setup shell scripts etc to run via Run->External Tools.  You can also get version control support (Subclipse/Subversive for SVN, MercurialEclipse and Java Git).

Answer (score 4):

[NetBeans with Mercurial](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HgHowTos)

Answer (score 2):

Use emacs. it has mercurial, git etc. support. it is cross-platform and free.

Comment: Also, mentioning emacs causes people to say "vim."

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [Geany](http://geany.org).  It's fairly lightweight, supports syntax highlighting for a variety of languages and has a plugin for most popular version control systems.